# Find Green's function where derivative is $0$ at endpoints?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, dirac-delta, greens-function

The problem is as follows,

$$G_{xx}(x,k) = - \delta(x-k) \tag{1} $$
$$ G_x(0,k) = G_x(1,k) = 0 \tag{2} $$

Is this possible? From what I understand,

(1) implies $G(x,k)$ is continuous and piecewise linear, but the conditions in (2) then imply that $G_x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, no such solution can exist: if it did, we would have by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
$$ 0 = G_x(1,k) - G_x(0,k) = \int_0^1 G_{xx}(x',k) \, dx' = \int_0^1 -\delta(x'-k) dx' = -1 ,$$
which is obviously wrong.